# Read file to int array

Tags: android, file-io

Hi I have a file which contains numbers split by comma and space e.g.:

```
[ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,

   0, 0, 1, 0, 1 ]
```

To read them to int array im using this:

```
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        file = new int[20][20];
        is = activity.getAssets().open(f);

        for (int i = 0;i < file.length; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < file[i].length; j++) {
                file[i][j] = Character.getNumericValue(is.read());

                is.read();
                is.read();
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("file", "exception: " + e);
```

But what if i have higher numbers like 12 e.g.:

```
[ 0, 1, 10, 10, 0,

   0, 0, 12, 0, 11 ]
```

How to read it to the array?

Comment: read a string and use String.split (or even, if you happen to notice that this is a valid JSON format, a JSONArray from your String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply use the `String[] temp = value.split(",");` Method to split it at `,`. And i guess you are done. If there are Whitespaces delete those befor with this method: `String temp = temp.replace(" ", "");` 
 And if there are backspaces delte those also with an replace statement. But you just need to do this if you parse the Strings to Integer later on. A Backspace does nullpointers than.

```
String value = value.replace("\r\n", "").replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
```

to replace the backspaces.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think that in a first time you should split your line in an array of String, and then convert each value of the tab in an int.

```
String[] lineValues = line.split(","); //to split
```